# Javafx tableview adding image

Tags: image, javafx, tableview, addition

```
@FXML private javafx.scene.control.TableView<User> userTableView;

@FXML private TableColumn<User, Image> isActiveColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn<User, String> userNameColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn<User, String> taskColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn<User, String> firstNameColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn<User, String> lastNameColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn<User, String> editDeleteColumn;

public static ObservableList<User> data;

public void initialize() throws SQLException {
   try {
       data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        addUsers();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void clickAddUser() throws Exception{

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/addUser.fxml"));
    Parent root =  fxmlLoader.load();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.show();
}

//tablewiev'e kullanici eklenmesi
public void addUsers() throws SQLException {
    try {
        List<User> userList = Main.dbManager.getUserList();

     if(userList.size() != 0){
            for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++){
                User aUser = userList.get(i);
                data.add(aUser);
            }
        }

        isActiveColumn.setMinWidth(200);
        isActiveColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<User, Image>, TableCell<User, Image>>() {
            public TableCell<User, Image> call(TableColumn<User, Image> param) {

                final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
                imageView.setFitHeight(50);
                imageView.setFitWidth(50);

                    TableCell<User, Image> cell = new TableCell<User, Image>(){

                        @Override
                        protected void updateItem(Image item, boolean empty) {
                            if(item != null)
                              imageView.setImage(new Image("images/if_User-green_85406.png"));
                        }

                    };
                    cell.setGraphic(imageView);
                    return cell;
            }
        });
        isActiveColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, Image>("image"));

        userNameColumn.setMinWidth(200);
        userNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("aUsername"){
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<User, String> param) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(param.getValue().getUsername());
            }
        });

        taskColumn.setMinWidth(200);
        taskColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("aTask"){
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<User, String> param) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(param.getValue().getTask());
            }
        });

        firstNameColumn.setMinWidth(200);
        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("aFirstname"){
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<User, String> param) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(param.getValue().getFirstname());
            }
        });

        lastNameColumn.setMinWidth(200);
        lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("aLastname"){
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<User, String> param) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(param.getValue().getLastname());
            }
        });

        editDeleteColumn.setMinWidth(200);
        editDeleteColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("editDeleteCol"));

        userTableView.setItems(data);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ObservableList<User> getData(){
    return data;
}
```

}

I want to add image if is active or passive. I add active or passive state boolean. I don't know how it will be but before that I try to add static image updateItem method is never called. Could you help about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `User` class defines a boolean property `active`, i.e.

```
public class User {

    private final BooleanProperty active = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    public BooleanProperty activeProperty() {
       return active ;
    }

    public final boolean isActive() {
        return activeProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setActive(boolean active) {
        activeProperty().set(active);
    }

    // other properties...
}
```

then you should make the `isActiveCol` a `TableColumn<User, Boolean>` and set it up as:

```
@FXML private TableColumn<User, Boolean> isActiveColumn;

// ...

public void addUsers() {

    // ...

    isActiveColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("active"));

    isActiveColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> {
        final Image activeImage = new Image(...);
        final Image passiveImage = new Image(...);
        TableCell<User, Boolean> cell = new TableCell<User, Boolean>() {
            private ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Boolean active, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(active, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    if (active) {
                        imageView.setImage(activeImage);
                    } else {
                        imageView.setImage(passiveImage);
                    }
                    setGraphic(imageView);
                }
            }
        };
        return cell ;
    });
}
```

Comment: I did what you say but 'active' parameter is null. So it gives NullPointerException?

Comment: I don't see any way the `active` parameter can be null when the cell is non-empty. I changed the initialization of the property in the `User` class, but I don't think that makes any difference. Are you sure that is the problem?

Comment: I changed    isActiveColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("active")); "active" to isActive and it works. Thanks...

Comment: @user1020141 That parameter to `PropertyValueFactory` needs to match the method name in `User`: I have `activeProperty()` and `isActive()`, so it should be `"active"` in that case. If your method names are different, you would need a different parameter. (You should mark this answer as correct if it works for you.)